# Measure production workload of Serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

Is there a good way to measure % of my produciton workload utilize serverless including(FaaS or Managed services)? I can definitely see more and more serverless adaption but it will be good to have some metrcis to back that up.

One of the way I was thinking of is to use monitoring tools like new relic or datadog etc. to find out number of services running in produciton , ofcourse for that all the services needs to be integrated with serverless application

Answer (score 0):

You're not really describing what you mean by *percentage*.

- Is it the percentage of compute (how do you factor in serverless databases like dynamo and aurora serverless)?
- Is it percentage compared to alternatives (EC2 vs Fargate & Lambda)? You might be able to compare stored data and transaction volume between things like RDS and Aurora Serverless... but how would you compare Fargate or Lambda vs EC2?
- How do fully managed services play a role (SNS, SQS, or EventBridge)?

I can appreciate the desire to measure serverless adoption, but I don't know if it's that clean.

The only thing that maybe makes sense is to compare costs over time - and even that's not very clean. Regardless, to do that you can go to your [AWS Cost & Usage Report](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-and-usage-reporting/) (in [AWS Cost Explorer](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home)). There you can see a breakdown of all of the your costs by service. You can do the math to see how much of your spend is towards serverless or non-serverless products (assuming you know which services are serverless and not). If you have [activated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/activating-tags.html) any cost allocation tags for use within cost explorer then you can filter further by those tags as well.

Compare that change over time and you'll see what % of services you pay for are serverless, and which aren't.

Comment: yeah, that's sort of a challenge that's making it difficult to come up with metrics on measure serverless adaption. Maybe I just look at how many AWS  services are in use and out of that I can measure how many serverless services are in use . Cost explorer gives that view of all services. It may still not be accurate because Lambda@edge will not come as a separate service because it comes as part of the CloudFront.

Comment: @NSS the thing is that fully managed services like CloudFront are often still considered serverless (you don't have to purchase/provision any servers).